# Retrieving Data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "ID" : 7,
    "vendor" : "Gold's Gym",
    "savings" : 50,
    "value" : 300,
    "description" : "Get a 3 month membership for $250 ($300 value)",
    "terms" : "Non transferrable",
    "product" : "Membership",
    "expires" : {
            "year" : 2017,
            "month" : 7,
            "date" : 31
    },
    "code" : "GYM-1",
    "tags" : [
            "fitness"
    ]
},
{
    "ID" : 8,
    "vendor" : "Golds Gym",
    "discount" : 15,
    "description" : "Get 15% discount on fitness classes",
    "terms" : "Non transferrable",
    "exceptions" : "Not applicable to swimming classes",
    "product" : "Classes",
    "purchaseValidity" : {
            "year" : 2017,
            "month" : 7,
            "date" : 31
    },
    "expires": {
            "year" : 2017,
            "month" : 12,
            "date" : 31
    },
    "code" : "GYM-2",
    "tags" : [
            "fitness"
    ]
}
```

This is part of a lager code. However,  I want to retrieve the data items with tag: fitness  that offer discounts:  $gte 10 or savings above 10

This is what I started working with, however I cant find the syntax to work with both discounts and fitness

```
items.find({tags: "fitness"}, {discount: {$gte: 10}}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Do it like this :-

1.[$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) used for match in arrays.

2.$and in by Default in query.

```
items.find({ tags:{  $elemMatch:{$eq: "fitness"}} ,
             $or:[  {discount: {$gte: 10}},
                    {savings: {$gte: 10}} 
                 ] })
```

Thanks.